# How to reduce list of tuples/lists with equal elements to sub graphs?

Tags: python

Given I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('f', 'g'), ('e', 'f'), ('b', 'd')]
```

or

```
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['f', 'g'], ['e', 'f'], ['b', 'd']]
```

I want to merge every tuple/list that has one matching element (the position doesn't matter).

The above should result in (order doesn't matter):

```
[['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], ['f', 'g', 'e']]
```

For sure I could write a recursive function merging every tuple/list until there is no more merge able tuple/list.

But I'm looking for a existing function / function in python or in a package that can do this preferably in a one liner.

Comment: There are no built-ins that do this. Striving to use one-liners is ... a bad heuristic.

Comment: Only adjacent ones?

Comment: This isn't really a "tuple" question or a "list" question. It's a graph problem: you're trying to find [connected components of an undirected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). There are many published algorithms for doing this.

Comment: @JoeIddon Adjacent in which way? The position of elements in a tuple/list shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Spen Sorry, I was mistaken, I get it now

Comment: @amalloy For example? Are there any that are already implemented and useable in python?

Comment: @Spen not in the standard library, as far as I know.

Comment: You should look at Union-Find algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: There are many existing algorithms for finding components of a graph.

Comment: In the end I need a algorithm that creates a forest of spanning trees. But I can't find an existing implementation in a package that I could use with my given list. I guess something like Kruskal or Chazelle would help, but again I can't find an existing package implementation.

Comment: A problem is, that I need a really efficient algorithm. A simple breadth search or depth search doesn't cut it.

Comment: @Spen: there are already lots of set consolidation/connected component questions on SO, and while library requests are off-topic, library implementations are very common (both scipy and networkx have them, e.g. `list(nx.connected_components(nx.from_edgelist(lst)))` should work.)  It's not clear to me what you're asking which is both (1) on-topic and (2) not a duplicate.

Comment: @DSM Yes, this is the answer I was looking for. If you write it as answer to this question (preferable including the networkx and scipy solution) I will except it as answer. The networkx solution worked great!

Comment: @Spen: again, to quote the rules, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  If that's what you're looking for, this question is definitely off-topic.

Comment: @DSM My question isn't opinion based since there is only one sort of correct answer to my question. The one you just gave. I was searching for a build-in method to solve the graph problem I described. I don't care if it is python nativ or from any common package as long as I don't have to write a algorithm for it and as long as it is efficient. The solution you provided seems to check both marks. It's not that you are the creator of these packages or advertising for them. You even provided two alternatives. I don't see anything wrong with that.